# Encrypt connection within SQL Server, and client using ADO? (not ADO.NET, just ADO)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, encryption, connection

The thing is that due to my present architecture of application I want just to encrypt connection within SQL Server, and ADO.

Do someone know the way to do that? Is it possible?

I made some research and I know that I can do that with ADO.NET, but i can't find anything about ADO.

Comment: If your connection string is using a windows credential then windows is automatically encrypting the connection between remote and local machines.

Comment: @jdweng But is it encrypting data which is sending from SQL Server to client application, or just informations about users? Maybe you have got some links where I can read something more about that?